# multiple htaccess rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am struggling since last couple of hours to get it worked but no luck.. if any help will really be great.

```
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
   RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ details.php?profile=$1 [L,NC,QSA] 
   RewriteRule ^industry/(.*)$ category.php?industry=$1 [L,NC,QSA] 
   RewriteRule ^page/(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteRule . /index.php [R=301,L]
```

very complex is it? but really not it is easy but when i am trying to add one more rule in above set of rules it is not working.

actual url - `http://www.examples.com/req-info.php?tag=denis-reach-home&about=denis-reach&info=home`

To URL -  `http://www.examples.com/tag/denis-reach-home/denis-reach/home`

i tried varies things but no luck.. e.g -

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /req-info.php?tag=$1&about=$2info=$3 [L]
```

any expert can share some tips.

thank you in advance.

Comment: _If_ you have access to the http server configuration: turn on rewrite logging and check what happens inside the rewrite engine.

Comment: arkascha - thanks but i dont have access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. Have this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ details.php?profile=$1 [L,NC,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^industry/(.*)$ category.php?industry=$1 [L,NC,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^page/(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# your new rule
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ req-info.php?tag=$1&about=$2info=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @anubhava.. thank you very much it resolved my issue.  But not able to understand why this ([^/]*) did not work but this ([^/]+) anyways thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. `([^/]*)` could also work but in your RewriteRule you just had `([^/]*)` twice but in your URL you have 3 segments.